# Can CSS Box shadow flow onto items below it?

Tags: css

Is there a way cover an item below with the box shadow of the item above it?

Please take look at:[this example](http://pastehtml.com/view/1dhata0.html)

Is there a way to cover the the white box with the shadow of the red box? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you can stop the refreshing of the page every 3 secs, then maybe we can have a look at it ...

Answer (score 2):

Give both boxes `position: relative` and give the red box a higher `z-index` than the white box:

```
#d1, #d2 {
    position: relative;
}

#d1 {
    /* Other styles */
    z-index: 1;
}

#d2 {
    /* Other styles */
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#red-box { z-index: 2000; }
#white-box { z-index: 1000; }
```

A higher z-index means that it'll be placed on top of lower z-indexed items.

---

By the way, very useful that your page reloads itself so I cannot change the stylesheet from Web Inspector to test this.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot that you need to set the position to relative: `position: relative;`, but @BoltClock was first.

Answer (score 0):

If you give it (*the top one*) `position:relative` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

set position: relative on div 1 before tinkering with z-index